# Pass Information From System verilog Testbench to a C++ Program Using pipes

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

I want to be able to pass information from System Verilog testbench to a c++ program through a pipe. Is there a way to implement this.

Comment: from system verilog you can call a 'C' function using the DPI interface. The latter can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on Linux, you can a [named pipe](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156) file and have your testbench write to it. Then you can use that file as input to your program.

But a much more efficient solution is using SystemVerilog's DPI to pass the information by linking your C++ program into the simulation.